# Was beudeutet Halbundhalbgott?

Tags: meaning

Im Steppenwolf von Hesse gibt es den folgenden Satz:

> Wer die anderen Tage geschmeckt hat, die bösen, die mit den Gichtanfällen   oder die mit jenem schlimmen, hinter den Augäpfeln festgewurzelten, teuflisch jede Tätigkeit von Auge und Ohr aus einer Freude zur Qual verhexenden Kopfweh, oder jene Tage des Seelensterbens, jene argen Tage der inneren Leere und Verzweiflung, an denen uns, inmitten der zerstörten und von Aktiengesellschaften ausgesogenen Erde, die Menschenwelt sogenannte Kultur in ihrem verlogenen und gemeinen blechernen Jahrmarktsglanz auf Schritt und Tritt wie ein Brechmittel entgegengrinst, konzentriert und zum Gipfel der Unleidlichkeit getrieben im eigenen kranken Ich – wer jene Höllentage geschmeckt hat, der ist mit solchen Normal- und Halbundhalbtagen gleich dem heutigen sehr zufrieden, dankbar sitzt er am warmen Ofen, dankbar stellt er beim Lesen des Morgenblattes fest, daß auch heute wieder kein Krieg ausgebrochen, keine neue Diktatur errichtet, keine besonders krasse Schweinerei in Politik und Wirtschaft aufgedeckt worden ist, dankbar stimmt er die Saiten seiner verrosteten Leier zu einem gemäßigten, einem leidlich frohen, einem nahezu vergnügten Dankpsalm, mit dem er seinen stillen, sanften, etwas mit Brom betäubten **Zufriedenheitshalbundhalbgott** langweilt, und in der laudicken Luft dieser zufriedenen Langeweile, dieser sehr dankenswerten Schmerzlosigkeit sehen die beiden, der öde nickende **Halbundhalbgott** und der leicht angegraute, den gedämpften Psalm singende **Halbundhalbmensch**, einander wie Zwillinge ähnlich.

Ich kann die Wörter nicht verstehen, die  mit Halbundhalb- anfangen. 
Weder das Wörterbuch noch die Internetsuche helfen mir.

Comment: Ein Halbgott ist ein halber Gott. Zwei Halbe machen ein Ganzes. Es handelt sich also um einen ganzen Gott, in Fachkreisen auch *Vollgott* genannt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das ist dichterischer Sprachgebrauch, und deshalb in der Tat schwer zu verstehen.

1. *Halb und halb* bedeutet wörtlich: *gemischt*, *aus zwei verschiedenen Bestandteile bestehend*.
2. In der Mythologie ist ein *Halbgott* eine Figur, die einen göttlichen und einen menschlichen Elternteil hat, zum Beispiel Achill, oder Herakles. Ein Halbgott ist also halb ein Mensch und halb ein Gott.

Mit dem Begriff *Halbundhalbtag* führt Hesse das Präfix *Halbundhalb-* in dieser Passage ein: Es handelt sich um einen ganz gewöhnlichen Tag, an dem nichts besonderes passiert, es ist ein Tag ohne historische Bedeutung. Hesse führt hier also das von ihm eigens eingeführten Präfix *Halbundhalb-* als Gegensatz zu *extrem*, *unvermischt* (auch: *rein*) ein, und gibt ihm damit die Bedeutung *vermischt*, wobei *vermischt* hier automatisch als *durchschnittlich* gedacht wird. Diese Bedeutung hat das Präfix auch bei den beiden anderen Worten *Halbundhalbgott* und *Halbundhalbmensch*: Hesse deutet hier gerade an, dass der Halbundhalbgott so wenig außergewöhnlich ist, dass er im Grunde dem *Halbundhalbmenschen* schon völlig gleicht ("wie Zwillinge"): der *Halbundhalbgott* hat also gar nichts Göttliches mehr an sich, außer dass er vom *Halbundhalbmenschen* in Psalmen besungen wird. *Halbundhalb-* zeigt hier an, dass das Charakteristische durch Vermischung unkenntlich gemacht, aufgelöst worden ist. Hesse spielt damit nebenbei ironisch auf ein "abgekühltes" und [säkularisiertes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A4kularisierung) Religionsverständnis und eine abgekühlte Religionsausübung an.

Die ganze Wortschöpfung ist überhaupt ein starkes Ironiesignal. Generell ist die Passage stark [kulturpessimistisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulturpessimismus); in ihr drückt sich das Verständnis aus, dass die Kultur für die Dämpfung der Affekte verantwortlich ist, gleichzeitig wird diese mäßigende Funktion der Kultur durch Übertreibung zugespitzt und Kultur implizit als ein [Sedativum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedierung) kritisiert.

Comment: *Mett halb und halb* – gemischtes Hackfleisch (Rind+Schwein) für Buletten. Und genau so soll man das wohl auch verstehen.

Comment: Anderes Beispiel aus der Kulinarik: *Kartoffelklöße halb und halb* - zur Hälfte aus rohen und zur Hälfte aus gekochten Kartoffeln hergestellt.

Comment: @Janka, Rha Ja, die Verwendung von _halb und halb_ ist aber nicht auf die Küche beschränkt, deswegen schrecke ich davor zurück, diese Beispiele in die Antwort aufzunehmen - weil nicht klar ist, warum hier gerade auf die Kulinarik angespielt werden soll.